# Legacy SubMatrix function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, compatibility

I've started updating *Mathematica* code published in a 2000 paper:

[Algorithms Behind Term Structure Models of Interest Rates II: The Hull-White Trinomial Tree of Interest Rates](https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=296064003086020019018124075000003023019084051044068022009102079005118006061020013120049027121075108122015124026117072070049032017124122102024021078120066080070043033069074116092003073065114103093118072069064121017000074114008087103090030119081&EXT=pdf)

The original code loads the legacy package `` LinearAlgebra`MatrixManipulation `` from which it used the function:

```
SubMatrix[]
```

For a bit of context, the author uses the function in a `Which` statement within an `Append[]`:

```
Append[SubMatrix[XX, {2, 2}, {-jmin + jmax - 1, -jmin + jmax + 1}],
 Delete[XX[[-1]], {{1}, {2}}]]
```

Can anyone describe what this function did in 2000 and then direct me to ways to do it in more recent versions of *Mathematica* (I currently use 10.3.0.0)?

Comment: Search (e.g., with Google) for "mathematica LinearAlgebra MatrixManipulation" to obtain several references.

Comment: `Take[]` or `Part[]` + `Span[]` should prove more than adequate to replace that old function.

Comment: @J.M. -- Appears that `Take[]` has an exit replacement. -- Thx.

Comment: @J.M. - I spoke to soon.  See below.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that it was a direct plug-in replacement; just that `Take[]` with properly set parameters can be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @J.M. in the comments `Take[]` appears to provide an exact replacement for the legacy, `SubMatrix[]` (although one has to dig into the documentation to find it, listed as the 6th example under Take...Scope in version 10.3.0.0).

```
SubMatrix[XX, {2, 2}, {-jmin + jmax - 1, -jmin + jmax + 1}]

Take[XX, {2, 2}, {-jmin + jmax - 1, -jmin + jmax + 1}]
```

Well... Mr.Wizard called it properly in the 1st comment to this question.  The above is indeed incorrect.

Let's try again...with Mr.Wizard's example:

```
m = Partition[Alphabet[], 4];
SubMatrix[m, {1, 1}, {2, 2}]

{{"a", "b"}, {"e", "f"}}
```

Now look at the following `Take[]`

```
Take[m, {1, 2}, {1, 2}]


{{"a", "b"}, {"e", "f"}}
```

I think that gets it (even it my answer got there in a roundabout way).
Still not certain why the legacy `SubMatrix` worked differently than `Take`.

Comment: FWIW a concise equivalent: `Take[XX, {2}, {-1, 1} + jmax - jmin]` -- however I believe that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - As always, nice to have you on the case.

Answer (score 2):

The legacy package is here: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6770/

```
TakeMatrix[mat_?MatrixQ, start:{startR_Integer, startC_Integer},
end:{endR_Integer, endC_Integer}] :=
    Take[mat, {startR, endR}, {startC, endC}] /;
    And @@ Thread[Dimensions[mat] >= start] && 
    And @@ Thread[Dimensions[mat] >= end]

SubMatrix[mat_List, start:{_Integer, _Integer}, dim:{_Integer,_Integer}] :=
    TakeMatrix[mat, start, start+dim-1]
```

This is *not* directly equivalent to [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take.html):

```
m = Partition[Alphabet[], 4];

SubMatrix[m, {1, 1}, {2, 2}]
Take[m, {1, 1}, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"e", "f"}}
>
> {{"b"}}
> ```

A *terse* but *inefficient* equivalent, omitting the argument tests:

```
subMat[mat_, start_, dim_] := Array[mat[[##]] &, dim, start]
```

Comment: `Take[m,{1,2},{1,2}]` gives the same output as `SubMatrix[m, {1, 1}, {2, 2}]` in your example.  Did that big a change happen in defining positions of Lists?  Just trying to understand the thinking that took the legacy code to the current.

Comment: @Jagra I think it is just two different ways of looking at the same thing.  I don't see a big *change*, merely that `SubMatrix` wasn't apparently considered important enough to make a kernel function.  `Take` has existed since version 1.0 so it's not a matter of one function *replacing* the other, but rather about the need or lack thereof for a complementary function.